# How can I make an image fill a column in Drupal10?

Tags: drupal, containers, bootstrap-5, responsive-images

I am building a site in Drupal10 using Bootstrap Barrio (bootstrap5).  I am using the responsive grid to set columns at different screen sizes.  I want to get the main image of an article to exactly fill the container.  Drupal Image Styles set size by pixel, which isn't responsive.  I can see that I need to add "class=img-fluid" somewhere, but I am not sure where.  I also see that I can make an image style responsive in Drupal, but it seems to be based on an image that extends the full width of the screen, not the container width.